# How to calculate this summation

Tags: summation

```
η = 0.05211184484645051`;
Sum[η/(r + 1) + ArcTan[η/(r + 1)]
```

$r$ start from $0$.

How to calculate this summation until it becomes less than 10^-5?

Comment: Do you mean `η/(r + 1) + ArcTan[η/(r + 1)` less than `10^-5`?

Comment: "... until **it** becomes ..."  Which "it".  There are three plausible "it"s here: the partial sum, the summand, and the difference between the partial sum and the sum to $r = \infty$.  (Of course, one has to interpolate that you mean the sum from $r = 0$ to $r = \infty$, since you do not explicitly say so.)

Answer (score 6):

First determine for what value of $r$ the argument is less than $10^{-5}$:

```
η = 0.05211184484645051`;
sol = Solve[{η/(r + 1) + ArcTan[η/(r + 1)] == 1*^-5, r > 0}, r]

(* Out: {{r -> 10421.4}} *)
```

Then use that value as the upper limit in your summation:

```
Sum[η/(r + 1) + ArcTan[η/(r + 1)], {r, 0, Ceiling[r /. First@sol]}]

(* Out: 1.02436 *)
```

Comment: 10*^-5 not 1^-5 as you write

Comment: even that the answer is 1.02436 not less than 0.00001

Comment: @Mfafa The expression `a*^b` indicates `a * 10^b`, so $10^{-5}$ is written `1*^-5`. Instead `10*^-5` = $10^{-4}$. See [Input Syntax - Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977).

Comment: @Mfafa Finally, even for $r=0$ the first element of the sum is already much more than $10^{-5}$. So maybe you should explain what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Sum[\[Eta]/(1 + r) + ArcTan[\[Eta]/(1 + r)], {r, 0, n}]
```

is given by

```
\[Eta]*EulerGamma - (1/2)*I*LogGamma[1 - I*\[Eta]] + (1/2)*I*LogGamma[1 + I*\[Eta]] + 
(1/2)*I*LogGamma[2 - I*\[Eta] + n] - (1/2)*I*LogGamma[2 + I*\[Eta] + n] + 
\[Eta]*PolyGamma[0, 2 + n]
```

The sum and the analytic expression diverge for n->Infinity.

For n > 10421 each additional summand is less than 10^-5. The value of the sum at this point is 1.02436

Comment: +1.It should be noticed that `\[Eta] = 0.05211184484645051`;
`NSum[\[Eta]/(r + 1) + ArcTan[\[Eta]/(r + 1)], {r, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]` results in `0.904259` and no error commnication.

Comment: it is bigger than the harmonic series multiplied by eta, so should still diverge...

Comment: I see. I noticed the wrong answer of `NSum` for the developers.

Comment: I try to complete my work with this answer, but still wrong

Comment: \[Phi] = -2*\[Eta] (0.57721 + Log[q/2 K1]) + (2*
     Sum[\[Eta]/(r + 1) + ArcTan[\[Eta]/(r + 1)]        the value of K1=1.16

Comment: @Mfafa ??, please describe your problem precisely,.